# An analysis exercise involving an inequality with a real function and its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f : [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a non-null function of class $C^1$ in $(0,\infty)$. Also suppose that  there exists a constante $\rho > 0$ such that
$$
0 \leq x f'(x) \leq \rho f(x), \forall x > 0. \quad\quad\quad\quad(1)
$$
I would like to know if under these conditions we get $f(x) > 0,$ for all $x > 0$.

**My attempt:** From (1) we get $f(x) \geq 0,$ for all $x > 0$ and $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x > 0$. So, since $f$ is differentiable in $(0,\infty)$ it is non-decreasing, that is, if $0 < x  < y$, then $f(x) \leq f(y)$. Suppose by contradiction that exists an $x_0 > 0$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$. By $(1)$, $f'(x_0) = 0$. Also, since $f$ is non-null, there exists an $x_1 > x_0$ such that $f(x_1) > 0$. Yet, since $f$ is non-decresing, we get $f(y) = 0,$ for all $y \in [0,x_0]$.

At this point I don't know what to do. I tried to think in a counterexample for the statement, but I filed. Any suggestion with the proof or the non-veracity of the statement would be very good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x > 0$ is $xf'(x) \le \rho f(x)$ equivalent to $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{-\rho}f(x)) \le 0$, which shows that the function $x^{-\rho}f(x)$ is decreasing on $(0, \infty)$.

Therefore, if $f(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0 > 0$ then

- $f$ is zero on $[0, x_0]$ (because $f$ is nonnegative and increasing),
- and $f$ is also zero on $[0, \infty)$ (because $x^{-\rho}f(x)$ is nonnegative and decreasing).

It follows that $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: Dear Martin, thank you very much for your reply. I still can't see how inequality (1) is equivalent to $x^{-\rho}f(x)$ to be decreasing for $x > 0$. Could you please clarify this?

Comment: @Thiago: The derivative is $\le 0$.

Comment: That's true, now I can see. Once again, thank you, you helped me a lot.